# regex for phrase searching

Tags: c#, regex, linq, pattern-matching, phrase

I have to search phrase in big string may be length of 500 or 600 or greater now I have to check whether phrase exist or not

```
 phrase =  "Lucky Draw"

big string1  = "I'm looking for Lucky Draw a way to loop through the sentences and check"

big string1  = "I'm looking for  specialLucky Draw a way to loop through the sentences and check"

big string3  = "I'm looking for Lucky Draws a way to loop through the sentences and check"

bool success = Regex.Match(message, @"\bLucky Draw\b").Success;
```

I am doing the above workaround but it does not  satisfy all cases.

what I have to do when I have multiple phrases, I want to use `linq` in that case like :

```
bool success = Regex.Match(message,  **arrayofstrings**).Success;
```

Comment: What cases does it not match?  Do you want to match the `specialLucky Draw` in your second example?  - If so its pretty clear you cannot use a boundary ...

Comment: yes  you are right i have already observed this
now i just want to do this using linq ** Regex.Match(message, arrayofstring).Success**

Comment: Try `(?<=\s)Lucky\sDraw` to avoid matching  `specialLucky Draw`

Comment: can you please answer the second part

Comment: You can use LINQ to do multiple tests - why use Regex if you are just searching for a matching substring? Please update your question with the correct answers to the comments. `arrayOfStrings.Any(s => message.Contains(s))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a loop to build one large regex of `\b(phrase one|phrase two|phrase three|etc)\b` from your array of phrases and then use that regex to match against your strings.